# Aligning a mesh file onto a larger meshfile

Tags: vertices

Im trying to find a way to align the mesh that is circled around onto the corresponding area on the larger mesh. i was hoping there would be a way to align them using similar points within the vertices but im so new to this program that i do not know where to start.

The smaller meshfile is a higher resolution of the same area.

[image: screencapture of blender]

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE! No there is no such thing. You have to manually align it and make sure the mesh you are overlapping is slightly higher then the other to avoid z-fighting issues.